# Need two different results from the same query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sapb1

I'm checking for the Initial and Final balance of a month, I've come up with a query to get either of them, but I need to show both results in the same query. I can't do subqueries cause I use `GROUP BY` in my query and as far as I know, I can't use it when doing subqueries. I would appreciate any pointers or suggestions more experienced SQL users provide.

```
DECLARE @Year INT SET @Year = 2016
DECLARE @Month varchar(4) SET @Month = '07'

SELECT T2.[Segment_0]+'-'+T2.[Segment_1]+'-'+T2.[Segment_2] Account,
T2.[AcctName], 
SUM(T0.[Debit])-SUM(T0.[Credit]) Balance
FROM  JDT1 T0  
INNER  JOIN OJDT T1  
ON  T1.[TransId] = T0.[TransId] 
INNER JOIN oact T2
ON T2.[AcctCode] = T0.[Account]
where t0.RefDate >= @From and convert(varchar(7), T0.RefDate ,111) < LTRIM(str(@Year)) + '/' + @Month --Initial
--where t0.RefDate >= @From and convert(varchar(7), T0.RefDate ,111) <= LTRIM(str(@Year)) + '/' + @Month --Final
GROUP BY T2.[Segment_0]+'-'+T2.[Segment_1]+'-'+T2.[Segment_2],T2.[AcctName]
order by T2.[Segment_0]+'-'+T2.[Segment_1]+'-'+T2.[Segment_2]
```

As you can see its only a matter of `LESS THAN` and `LESS OR EQUAL THAN` issue, but I need both results in my query. My lack of experience is making me break my head over this.

Comment: `where (first version that's less than ) OR ( second part that's less than or equal to)`?  Could it be that simple?

Comment: but they wouldn't be separated @scsimon , they're different results

Comment: what's inital and final? The Saldo Final?

Comment: Initial balance of the month, and final balance of the month @scsimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will work.. im sure if we had a better idea of the data structure we could come up with some subqueries that would work

```
DECLARE @Year INT
SET @Year = 2016
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(4)
SET @Month = '07'

SELECT  T2.[Segment_0] + '-' + T2.[Segment_1] + '-' + T2.[Segment_2] Account,
        T2.[AcctName],
        SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),T0.RefDate,111) < LTRIM(STR(@Year)) + '/' + @Month THEN T0.[Debit] END) - 
            SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),T0.RefDate,111) < LTRIM(STR(@Year)) + '/' + @Month THEN T0.[Credit] END) AS Intitial,
        SUM(CASE WHEN convert(varchar(7), T0.RefDate ,111) <= LTRIM(str(@Year)) + '/' + @Month THEN T0.[Debit] END) - 
            SUM(CASE WHEN convert(varchar(7), T0.RefDate ,111) <= LTRIM(str(@Year)) + '/' + @Month THEN T0.[Credit] END) AS Final
FROM    JDT1 T0
        INNER  JOIN OJDT T1 ON T1.[TransId] = T0.[TransId]
        INNER JOIN oact T2 ON T2.[AcctCode] = T0.[Account]
WHERE   t0.RefDate >= @From
GROUP BY T2.[Segment_0] + '-' + T2.[Segment_1] + '-' + T2.[Segment_2],
        T2.[AcctName]
ORDER BY T2.[Segment_0] + '-' + T2.[Segment_1] + '-' + T2.[Segment_2]
```

it might make more sense if you clean it up some using a CTE

```
DECLARE @Year INT
SET @Year = 2016
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(4)
SET @Month = '07'
DECLARE @YearMonth VARCHAR(7) = LTRIM(STR(@Year)) + '/' + @Month

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  T2.[Segment_0] + '-' + T2.[Segment_1] + '-' + T2.[Segment_2] [Account],
            T2.[AcctName],
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),T0.RefDate,111) [RefDate],
            T0.[Debit],
            T0.[Credit]
    FROM    JDT1 T0
            INNER  JOIN OJDT T1 ON T1.[TransId] = T0.[TransId]
            INNER JOIN oact T2 ON T2.[AcctCode] = T0.[Account]
    WHERE   t0.RefDate >= @From
)
SELECT  Account,
        AcctName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN RefDate < @YearMonth THEN [Debit] END) - SUM(CASE WHEN RefDate < @YearMonth THEN [Credit] END) AS Initial,
        SUM(CASE WHEN RefDate <= @YearMonth THEN [Debit] END) - SUM(CASE WHEN RefDate <= @YearMonth THEN [Credit] END) AS Final,
FROM    cte
GROUP BY Account,
        AcctName
ORDER BY Account
```

Comment: **Oh wow!** Would you mind guiding me trough your changes? It's not instant but 5 seconds its definitely an improvement from a 2 minute wait to show results!

Comment: you're wanting to subtract `SUM(T0.[Credit])` from `SUM(T0.[Debit])`  the `CASE EXPRESSIONS` inside your SUM Aggregate just limits which records to include in the SUM..  if the WHEN condition is met it adds the value, else it just ignores the value..

Comment: Yes it's much more clear for me with your edit plus your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need both, then just use `<=`. `<=` is going to get all rows that `<` than would, plus some... so using `<` is redundant. Aside from this operand, your where clauses are identical.

**EDIT**

Try This....

```
SELECT 
    T2.[Segment_0]+'-'+T2.[Segment_1]+'-'+T2.[Segment_2] Cuenta,
    T2.[AcctName], 
    ISNULL((select SUM([Debit]) - SUM([Credit]) from JDT1 where TransId = T0.TransID and RefDate >= @From and convert(varchar(7), RefDate ,111) < LTRIM(str(@Year)) + '/' + @Month),0) as [Initial Saldo Final],
    ISNULL((select SUM([Debit]) - SUM([Credit]) from JDT1 where TransId = T0.TransID and RefDate >= @From and convert(varchar(7), RefDate ,111) <= LTRIM(str(@Year)) + '/' + @Month),0) as [Final Saldo Final]
FROM    
    JDT1 T0  
    INNER  JOIN OJDT T1 ON
    T1.[TransId] = T0.[TransId] 
    INNER JOIN oact T2 ON
    T2.[AcctCode] = T0.[Account]
order by T2.[Segment_0]+'-'+T2.[Segment_1]+'-'+T2.[Segment_2]
```

Comment: Yes they're identical but `<` gives me all the results before the date I'm passing and `<=` includes the date being passed. It might not look like much but it means a lot to me that these results are separated.

Comment: @Justdoit Define separated? Like Two separate returns? Or just separated in the same result set?

Comment: One column for initial and one column for final, in the same result. I tried a subquery but wasn't able to accomplish it(maybe I was doing it wrong)

Comment: Thank you, it repeats `X` number of times the rows, and shows `0` for all balances